# RoR: Elasticsearch sort by mapped field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have Player and Player have fullname from Profil. I use elasticsearch on Player. I need default sort by fullname. How can I set it? My code from Player class file:

```
   ......
  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :fullname, boost: 10
    indexes :name
    indexes :surname
    indexes :position_name
    indexes :info
    indexes :club_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :club_name
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
      query do
        boolean do
          if params[:query].present?
            must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } 
          else
            must {string '*'}
          end
          must { term :position_id, params[:position_id]} if params[:position_id].present?
          must { term :club_id, params[:club_id]} if params[:club_id].present?
        end
      end
      # filter :term, user_id: params[:user_id] if params[:user_id].present?
      # sort { by Item.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at", %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc" } if params[:query].blank?

      sort { by Player.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : :id ,%w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"}
      facet "positions" do
        terms :position_id
      end
      facet "clubs" do
        terms :club_id
      end
      # raise to_curl
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:fullname, :name, :surname, :position_name, :club_name])
  end

  def fullname
        self.profil.fullname
  end
......
```

If I changed :id to :fullname in sort I have this error:

```
500 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[DBgvi6JiQAi0FTwhonq8Ag][players][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[players][0]: query[ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(_type:player)))],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:\"fullname\": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@33a626ac>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }{[DBgvi6JiQAi0FTwhonq8Ag][players][4]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[players][4]: query[ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(_type:player)))],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:\"fullname\": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@3274eb8a>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }]","status":500}
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue with sorting by name

Comment: sorry no, I use jQuery sort, but It's not good solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it!  After dumb amounts of research I found [this article here](https://groups.google.com/a/elasticsearch.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/users/90chQS9_GI0). The first answer mentions:

> The field user by default gets analyzed and broken down into one or more tokens. If it gets broken down into more than one token, then you can't really sort on it. If you want to sort on it, you either need to set it i(in the mappings) as not analyzed

In your situation, all you would need to do is:

```
 mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :fullname, :index => 'not_analyzed'
    indexes :name
    indexes :surname
    indexes :position_name
    indexes :info
    indexes :club_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :club_name
  end
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort { by Player.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : :fullname ,%w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"}
```

Changing 'id' to 'fullname' should work.